# Child repeater's item count

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to get the child repeater's item count but for some reason it keeps coming up as zero.  Here is my code:  Parent repeater is rptDays.  Child repeater is rptEditInfo.

```
protected void rptDays_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Repeater rptEditInfo = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("rptEditInfo");
        ...
        DateTime thisDay = (DateTime)e.Item.DataItem;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ...
        ds = **bind valid dataset to this variable**
        rptEditInfo.DataSource = MRSTable;
        rptEditInfo.DataBind();
   }
```

}

```
protected void rptEditInfo_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Header)
    {
        Repeater rpt2 = (Repeater)((Repeater)e.Item.Parent);
        Repeater rpt1 = (Repeater)((Repeater)sender).Parent.FindControl("rptEditInfo");
        int countTest1 = rpt2.Items.Count //always zero
        int countTest2 = rpt1.Items.Count //always zero
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?  The data is valid and populated.  Only thing I can think of is that I am not accessing the child repeater properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot get the item count in the header(`e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Header`). The items will be created in this order:

1. Header
2. `1.` Item `ItemCreated`    (Count=0 since not databound yet)
3. `1.` Item `ItemDataBound`  (Count=1 since first item created and databound)
4. `2.` Item `ItemCreated`    (Count=1 since not databound yet)
5. `2.` Item `ItemDataBound`  (Count=2 since second item created and databound)
   ....

So `ItemDataBound` is not the right stage to get the total count from the `Items` property. But always a better approach anyway is to use the datasource directly instead instead of counting Items(or Rows in a `GridView`).

```
protected void rptEditInfo_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Header)
    {
        Repeater rpt = (Repeater)sender;
        //note that this depends on your actual datasource, set a breakpoint and debug if you're unsure
        var dataSource = (DataView)rpt.DataSource; 
        int count = dataSource.Count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this enlightment, it totally makes sense.  A point up and an answer!

Answer (score 0):

You might have to bind the nested repeater in your first databound event

rptEditInfo.ItemDataBound += new System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventHandler(rptEditInfo_ItemDataBound);

this may help.
http://www.mostlylucid.co.uk/articles/nestedrepeaters.htm

Answer (score -1):

You can use refer following code and use to resolve you issue:

```
<<**** Global variable **************>>
Public static int innerRepeaterCount=0;

<<********* Your rptEditInfo_ItemDataBound event wiil be as follows*******>>



protected void rptEditInfo_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) 
{
    dv = e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView;  
   if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) 
    {
       nestedRCountInInnerR = nestedRCount;
       innerRepeaterCount++; 
    }
 }


 innerRepeaterCount will give you total item counts in inner Repeater
```